# Wordpress site still works when I shut down MySQL

Tags: nginx, mysql, apache-2.4, wordpress

I entered 'service mysqld stop' via SSH and noticed my site was still running. Better yet, it was running faster than ever.

"Shutting down MySQL....... SUCCESS!"

Anyone know why this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Your WP site stores database data in Memcache / APCU cache, and when you are accessing non-changing content, database accesses are not needed.

Comment: Could be any cache, even something like cloudflare. But yes, this is likely it, some caching mechanism has a copy of it and keeps serving it until it expires. Then it tries to fetch a new copy, including the necessary database queries, and then your strategy isn't so successful anymore. It's now a ticking downtime bomb.